# How to find all connected two edges in a large graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, social-networking, data-mining, graph-theory

I have a large graph (e.g., facebook network, twitter network), I want to find two connected edges. For example, like p1<--->p2<--->p3 in a social network, p1,p2,p3 are three different peoples, but they are connected. I know there is some algorithms for finding triangles, but besides the triangles, I also need to find the above component (that is, the component formed by deleting one edge from the triangle). 
BTW, is there a term for such a component?

THanks.

Comment: Do you mean 'connected nodes' instead of 'connected edges'?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you don't find a lot of publications on this is that it's an too easy problem.

If you have a symmetric relation, any two neighbors “a” and “c” of a node “b” form such a „1-transitive” connection: b is the link. The pseudocode for map-reduce is

```
def map(b, neighbors):
  for a in neighbors:
    for c in neighbors:
      if not a == c:
        send(a, c)
```

If the relation is not symmetric, just add another mapper to make it symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) of the input graph. Basically, these can be found by using [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). You start at some point in the graph. On termination, all visited nodes form one connected component. Then, you iterate by selecting the next unvisited node, discovering connected components until all nodes are visited.

Comment: Thanks. But I guess not. I think I'm looking for all paths with length =2 from a large graph.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and keep track of the recursion depth: once you get to depth 2, print all the nodes in your stack.

Repeat for each node, eliminating duplicates as needed.

I'm not aware of a specific term, you seem to want to find all paths of length 2 between any 2 nodes.